# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method myMethod(String) from the type [MyClassWhichIsExtendingActivity]

Tags: android, inheritance, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I am basically creating a **base** class that will overwrite (extend) classes such as Activity or FragmentActivity and add custom functionality by defining methods that should be available to any other class, that extends this **base** class.

The structure if the following, basically:

```
CustomActivity (extends)->BaseActivity (extends)->Activity
```

or

```
CustomActivity (extends)->BaseFragmentActivity (extends)->FragmentActivity
```

The base class in this situation is called `hmFragmentActivity` and it `extends FragmentActivity`. I've defined a custom method inside `hmFragmentActivity`:

```
public String pref(String key, String defaultVal) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    return prefs.getString(key, defaultVal);
}
```

Basically it's a helper method, which I want available in all other activities, by making them extend `hmFragmentActivity` instead of `FragmentActivity`.

However, when I try to call `prefs()` from any activity, it gets highlighted as an error in the IDE.

Here's an example:

```
public class FuelEconomy extends hmFragmentActivity {

  // In some method:
  if(pref("fuel_usage_liter", "")==""){
     Log.d("fuel", "Fuel set");
  }

}
```

When I highlight `pref()` above, the IDE says:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method pref(String)
>   from the type hmFragmentActivity

Comment: post the whole code. the only error  I can see is the way you compare string ( == is wrong, you should use equals or equalsIgnoreCase)

Comment: That method were you're calling `pref()` is static?

Comment: but why the compiler is complaining  about pref(String) ?

Comment: @blackbelt Because in the static context of that method there is no `this`(the current object0 to actual reference that method.

Comment: yes I can understand the difference between a no-static vs static. But why only a paramter

Comment: I should have menetioned that I am calling pref() inside a `new TextWatcher()` that is attached to an `EditText`. Maybe the context is wrong there? I tried setting `getBaseContext()` to a global variable in the `FuelEconomy` class and using `c.pref()` instead, but that didn't do the trick.

Comment: @Luksprog No, the method is non-static. It's exactly as I have quoted it in the question.

Comment: Then I'm assuming the `TextWatcher` instance is declared as static?

Comment: @ColorWP.com I think Luksprog is right, you are probably declaring the TextWatcher instance as static, that seems the only possibility to me :)

Comment: You were right guys. The TextWatcher instance itself was in a subclass of the main class (the one that extends the **base** class), and that subclass was declared static.